# SQL convert NVARCHAR from one date format to another

Tags: sql-server, date, type-conversion, ssms

I know this has been asked a lot but I can't figure out how to change dates in SSMS.
I'm having an issue in ssms where I can't convert a nvarhar set in
M/D/YYYY H:mm:ss: xm  format to YYYY-D-M H:MM:SS.
I understand I need to use the convert function, but It is outputting the wrong data.

Completed = 10/21/2020 1:52:23 PM

```
begin tran
update course
set resetdate = CONVERT(datetime, Completed, 111)
...
```

Output is Oct 21 2020  1:52PM
expected output is 2020-10-21
Also when I use 102 as an argument I get the same output as well.
Since SSMS has datetime formatted a certain way (YDM) the date I gave wouldn't work anyway.
I would need to tell it the format of the date I'm giving it and what I want to convert it to.

reference https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-system-functions/convert-string-to-datetime/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15
Various stack forums

Comment: `select convert(datetime,'10/09/2020  1:52:23 PM',111);` gives the correct datetime (notice the 2 spaces between `2020` and `1:52` )

Comment: MySQL and SQL Server are entirely different products. You need to check the appropriate documentation because they don't have the same features or syntax. From the code and links I presume you're using the latter, so I'm removing the wrong tag.

Comment: this table was not set up by me.